# Pylucene eclipse plugin

Tags: java, python, lucene, pylucene

Is there a Pylucene eclipse plugin? or am I missing something?

I want it for Auto complete.  Is the import structure same as java lucene

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), you need to add PyLucene to your import path. This can be done in the preferences pane somewhere under the PyDev section. (Sorry, I don't have PyDev installed on this computer so I can't be more specific.) Not having used PyLucene I can't tell you exactly which path you need to add, but it should be the path where you have PyLucene installed.

Comment: So how do you add the PyLucene path in your eclipse. and where is it installed in a Mac?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have access to any macs these days, so I can't answer that. Regarding PyDev (Eclipse), I'll check it out next week when I'm next at work (probably Tuesday).